# Oracle SQL dynamically select a column

Tags: dynamic

I have multiple tables which all have the same structure --except a couple of them have one column misnamed.  I would like a sql statement that would allow the user to select that misnamed column using the correct name (there are only 2 possible names for the column-the correct one and the wrong one).  I was thinking I could have the query first look at the all_tab_columns view to look up the table and decide which spelling of that column the table has to retrieve the data...

Answer (score 0):

I understand the difficulty of renaming/altering existing production tables, but it seems like the best solution to this problem is simply to update the misnamed tables with the correct column name.  Is there a reason (beyond extra work) that this is infeasible?

Comment: Unfortunately, updating the table columns is not an option.

Comment: This almost worked...the problem is that an error occurs in the decode statement because one of the column names is not present in the table clinical_studies...select clinical_study_id, NVL(decode(a,'STUDY',STUDY),DECODE('BADNAME',badname)) 
from 
(SELECT NVL(
(select column_name from all_tab_columns
where owner='RXA_DES'
and table_name='CLINICAL_STUDIES'
and column_name='BADNAME'),
(select column_name from all_tab_columns
where owner='RXA_DES'
and table_name='CLINICAL_STUDIES'
and column_name='STUDY')) as a
FROM dual